# Получение последнее значение поля из объектов <td>, начинающегося с текста

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет.
Есть разметка html типа:

```
<tr class="">
<td class="date">22:14</td>
<td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per</td>
<td width="100%">GG: Текст1</td></tr>

<tr class="">
<td class="date">22:17</td>
<td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per1</td>
<td width="100%">Текст2</td></tr>

<tr class="">
<td class="date">22:20</td>
<td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per</td>
<td width="100%">GG: Текст3</td></tr>

<tr class="">
<td class="date">22:20</td>
<td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per</td>
<td width="100%">Текст4</td></tr>
```

Подскажите, как при помощи js найти значение поля td начинающегося с GG:?
Если таких значений несколько, то брать последнее. В данном случае это Текст3. (Их может быть много)

Была попытка начать делать так. Но всё время получаю undefined.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

var selectionDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("other");

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length;i++)
//alert(divs[i].val);
{
   if(divs[i].val == selectionDiv)
   {
     var previous = divs[i - 1];
     var next = divs[i + 1];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так :

```js
const tds = [...document.getElementsByTagName('td')],
  gg = 'GG: ',
  filtered = tds.filter(e => e.textContent.startsWith(gg)).slice(-1)[0],
  a = filtered && filtered.textContent.substring(gg.length)

console.log(a)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="">
    <td class="date">22:14</td>
    <td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per</td>
    <td width="100%">GG: Текст1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="">
    <td class="date">22:17</td>
    <td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per1</td>
    <td width="100%">Текст2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="">
    <td class="date">22:20</td>
    <td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per</td>
    <td width="100%">GG: Текст3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="">
    <td class="date">22:20</td>
    <td class="other" style="white-space: nowrap;">Per</td>
    <td width="100%">Текст4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```